# JavaFX - bind property to properties of every element in observable Collection

Tags: list, binding, javafx

Does exist any method which bind BooleanProperty to conjunction of every element in ObservableList?

```
ObservableList<BooleanProperty> list;
list = FXCollections.observableList(new ArrayList<BooleanProperty>));
BooleanProperty emptyProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
emptyProperty.bind(Bindings.conunction(list));`
```

Is there such a method as:

```
static BooleanBinding conjunction(ObservableList<BooleanProperty> op)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no [conjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) api defined in the JavaFX 2.2 platform.

You could create a `ConjunctionBooleanBinding` (aka `AllTrueBinding`) by subclassing [BooleanBinding](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/binding/BooleanBinding.html).

Accept the [ObservableList](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) in the constructor of your new class, and use the [low level binding api](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm) in an overridden [computeValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/binding/BooleanBinding.html#computeValue%28%29) method to set the binding value based upon logically anding together all of the boolean values in the list.

Here is a sample implementation.  The sample could be further performance optimized and make use of WeakReferences, so it does not require manual disposition.

```
import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.collections.*;

public class AllTrueBinding extends BooleanBinding {
  private final ObservableList<BooleanProperty> boundList;
  private final ListChangeListener<BooleanProperty> BOUND_LIST_CHANGE_LISTENER =
    new ListChangeListener<BooleanProperty>() {
      @Override public void onChanged(
             ListChangeListener.Change<? extends BooleanProperty> change
          ) {
        refreshBinding();
      }
    };
  private BooleanProperty[] observedProperties = {};

  AllTrueBinding(ObservableList<BooleanProperty> booleanList) {
    booleanList.addListener(BOUND_LIST_CHANGE_LISTENER);
    boundList = booleanList;
    refreshBinding();
  }

  @Override protected boolean computeValue() {
    for (BooleanProperty bp: observedProperties) {
      if (!bp.get()) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }

  @Override public void dispose() {
    boundList.removeListener(BOUND_LIST_CHANGE_LISTENER);
    super.dispose();
  }

  private void refreshBinding() {
    super.unbind(observedProperties);
    observedProperties = boundList.toArray(new BooleanProperty[0]);
    super.bind(observedProperties);
    this.invalidate();
  }
}
```

And here is a test harness to demonstrate how it works:

```
import java.util.*;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class ListBindingTest {
  final BooleanProperty a = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);
  final BooleanProperty b = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);
  final BooleanProperty c = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);
  final BooleanProperty d = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);
  final ObservableList<BooleanProperty> booleanList =
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(a, b, c, d);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ListBindingTest().test();
  }

  private void test() {
    AllTrueBinding at = new AllTrueBinding(booleanList);

    System.out.println(at.get() + forArrayString(booleanList));

    b.set(false);
    System.out.println(at.get() + forArrayString(booleanList));

    b.set(true);
    System.out.println(at.get() + forArrayString(booleanList));

    booleanList.add(new SimpleBooleanProperty(false));
    System.out.println(at.get() + forArrayString(booleanList));

    booleanList.remove(3, 5);
    System.out.println(at.get() + forArrayString(booleanList));

    at.dispose();
  }  

  private String forArrayString(List list) {
    return " for " + Arrays.toString(list.toArray());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your advice.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily implement the method as follows:

```
public static BooleanBinding conjunction(ObservableList<BooleanProperty> list){   
  BooleanBinding and = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true).and(list.get(0));
  for(int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++){
    and = and.and(list.get(i));   
  }
  return and;
}
```