# Binding LongProperty to internal changes of ListProperty

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I have got three classes:

```
class A { 
    //Duration in seconds
    private val durationProperty = SimpleLongProperty(300)
    var duration by durationProperty
}
```

```
class B(list: List<A>) {
    private val aClassesProperty = SimpleListProperty(list.observable())
    val aClasses by aClassesProperty
}
```

```
class C(classB: B, repetitions: Int){
    private val bClassProperty = SimpleObjectProperty(classB)

    private val repetitionsProperty = SimpleIntProperty(repetitions)
    val repetitions by repetitionsProperty
}
```

Now I would like, to create and bind `durationProperty` inside `class B` as sum of `class A` `durationProperty` (which will be sensitive to adding new `class A` instance into list and changing any duration of already present instance) and similarly in `class C` - `durationProperty` as duration of `classB` multiplied by `repetitions`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know kotlin, but the answer should be easy to translate.

You need to use an 'extractor' to handle this, using:

```
FXCollections#observableArrayList(Callback<E, Observable[]> extractor)
```

Like:

```
ObservableList<A> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(item -> new Observable[] {item.durationProperty});

list.addListener((InvalidationListener) observable -> {
    //Update you sum here
});
```

The extractor causes any changes to the given observable array of each item in the list to trigger both the InvalidationListener and ListChangeListener of the list to be fired.

Answer (score 0):

SephB's solution is correct, but finally I used one from t[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918887/javafx-how-to-bind-multiple-properties-in-a-list). I found it a little bit more elastic even though there is a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: this is more a comment than an answer - please consider to move it as comment under the other answer :)