# Enabling/Disabling buttons in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

how do you disable buttons under a certain condition? For example, i have many text fields and buttons, when those text fields are empty one of my buttons should be disabled. i already have this code.

```
if(txtID.getText().isEmpty()&&txtG.getText().isEmpty()
            &&txtBP.getText().isEmpty()&&txtD.getText().isEmpty()
            &&txtSP.getText().isEmpty()&&txtCons.getText().isEmpty()){
       btnAdd.setDisable(true);
       }
else{
btnAdd.setDisable(false);
}
```

is there an easier way to do this? Also if i add text into those areas shouldnt the button be re enable its self?

Comment: That code should work.  Your logic does what you want it to do, if(any textbox is empty is empty) {disable button}.  It's a little messy but it works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a `BooleanBinding` using the textfield's `textProperty()` and then bind it with the Button's `disableProperty()`.

### For enabling the button if any of the textfields is not empty.

```
// I have added 2 textFields, you can add more...
BooleanBinding booleanBind = Bindings.and(text1.textProperty().isEmpty(),
                                              text2.textProperty().isEmpty());
button.disableProperty().bind(booleanBind);
```

**For more than 2 textfields**

```
BooleanBinding booleanBind = Bindings.and(text1.textProperty().isEmpty(),
          text2.textProperty().isEmpty()).and(text3.textProperty().isEmpty());
```

Or, a better approach is to use `and` directly on the property:

```
BooleanBinding booleanBind = text1.textProperty().isEmpty()
                            .and(text2.textProperty().isEmpty())
                                      .and(text3.textProperty().isEmpty());
```

### For enabling the button only if all of the textfields have text.

Just replace `and` with `or`.

```
BooleanBinding booleanBind = text1.textProperty().isEmpty()
                            .or(text2.textProperty().isEmpty())
                                      .or(text3.textProperty().isEmpty());
```

Comment: There are some interesting solutions for anding multiple boolean properties in the answers to: [bind property to properties of every element in observable Collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764401/javafx-bind-property-to-properties-of-every-element-in-observable-collection), though those answers are probably overkill for what the original poster is trying to achieve.

Comment: well this sorta worked, how come when i switched from ...

Comment: .add to .or it worked like it should. Also how come it will only take 2 text fields. More than one text field will give me an error in netbeans.

Comment: @ItachiUchihaok just so you know .or worked for me. not .and. thanks

Comment: @user3505212 Edited once more :)

Comment: it there a method ```isNumeric``` like ```isEmpty``` ? In order to enable/disable button if textfield is numeric !

Answer (score 0):

in swing we can disable a button as follow:

`JButton start = new JButton("Start");
start.setEnabled(false);`

but in javaFX this function(setEnabled)  changed to setDisabled, so we can use this code in javaFX:

`start.setDisable(false);`

Comment: Be careful of the wording: [`setDisabled()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setDisabled-boolean-) is a protected method not a public method and has a different meaning than the public [`setDisable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setDisable-boolean-) method.  The question poster is already using the correct method for his use case => `setDisable()`

Comment: FYI, the code snippet in this answer seems to have been corrected to `setDisable(...)` but the sentence it's used in still reads "setDisable**d**".